# Check for a process whenever I open gvim

Tags: linux, shell, vim, vi

I want to see if a process is running whenever I open a file using vim/gvim.

I added the following in .vimrc:

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep <process_name>
```

But it gives error :

> Error detected while processing /home/nj/.vimrc: line   15: E389:
>   Couldn't find pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.vimrc` is not a shell script file. Try this instead:

```
let process_ps = system("ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep <process_name>")
```

(or use `systemlist()`)

Comment: But it does not display any result?

Comment: No, puts it into a variable. If you want to display something, use `echo`.

Comment: can that be done in .vimrc or I have to do it after using editor command ?

Comment: It can be done in `.vimrc`; `.vimrc` commands *are* editor commands.